# Plugin InappBrowser not work on APK

Tags: android, cordova

I use the plugin inappbrowser to open some link like tel, website on a mobile application.
When i make a preview with phonegap developper it's work fine
But when i build it on phonegapbuild and dl it on my phone it's not work ( the plugin) . I click on the link but it's not open...
I try many solution in forum but it not work
Can somoene help me?

If i need to add the platform android to make it work ? or i not need because phonegap build will do it  alone.

Thanks you very much.

```
  config.xml <access origin="*"/> <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />

    index.html : <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
      }
    </script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script> detail.html :
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="open()">
            {{number.tel}}
        </button>

         controller.html for detail.html :
    $scope.open = function()
        {
            var test = $scope.number.tel;
            if(test =='A') {
                window.open('tel:01234567833');
            }
            else if(test == 'B'){
                window.open('tel:0456789122')
            }
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Yes, i will add the most important part of my code

Comment: Post the code and also pose the console log, mention which inappbrowser plugin you are using with version.

Comment: @StudentDevelopper12120 Enclose the device ready event addition code inside document ready or ionic platform ready function

Comment: read here  http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/
----------
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_in_app_browser.htm

Comment: @kishore.k.vaishnav i try it but it not work, i think it's outdated :s